# Mutex not locking

Tags: go, mutex

I noticed some unexpected behavior when using Mutex so I decided to write some test code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Box struct {
    Stuff int
    mu    sync.Mutex
}

var box Box

func init() {
    box = Box{}
    box.mu.Lock()
}

func (box *Box) add() {
    fmt.Println("add()")
    box.mu.Unlock()
    box.Stuff++
    box.mu.Lock()
}

func (box *Box) display() {
    fmt.Print("display(): ")
    box.mu.Unlock()
    fmt.Println(box.Stuff)
    box.mu.Lock()
}

func add2() {
    fmt.Println("add2()")
    box.Stuff++ //increments but should not, error expected
}

func display2() {
    fmt.Print("display2(): ")
    fmt.Println(box.Stuff) //displays but should not, error expected
}

func main() {
    box.display()
    box.add()
    box.display()
    display2()
    add2()
    box.display()
}
```

The functions without pointer receivers can add & access the protected struct.
Running the code.

```
display(): 0
add()
display(): 1
display2(): 1
add2()
display(): 2
```

I would expect the two functions which have the name appended with a 2 to fail.
They do not.

Any idea?

Comment: `display2` and `add2` don't use the lock at all, so there is no reason they shouldn't execute. What exactly do you expect to fail in those functions?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to write this a bit different:

You start by locking, which is not the most common way to use a lock: Everything is locked unless you unlock it.

A more common way is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Box struct {
    Stuff int
    mu    sync.Mutex
}

var box Box

func init() {
    box = Box{}
}

func (box *Box) add() {
    fmt.Println("add()")
    box.mu.Lock()
    box.Stuff++
    box.mu.Unlock()
}
...
```

Scoping your locks to the moment of change and not to the complete app.